# Observer in Dojo or Javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo

How to implement observer pattern in Dojo or Javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dojo it is very easy.

1. `dojo.connect` will allow you to add a callback on any function of any object.
2. dijit, Dojo's UI system, has a `watch` method to add a callback for any property change.

Now, in pure JavaScript, it is more involved, because you cannot trigger a callback for any arbitrary property update on any arbitrary object.  You can only "hijack" a property function so that it points to a new function, and that function does your callback after calling the original function.  However, you're essentially reimplementing `dojo.connect` so mind as well just go with Dojo.

Therefore, the observer pattern can only be implemented for function calls in JavaScript.

Comment: Unrelated question. Do you know if Google closure has something equivalent to dojo.connect?

Comment: Not sure, I don't use Closure Library myself, but you should read Michael Bolin's book Closure - the Definitive Guide and see if you find it.

Answer (score 7):

Though I'm not sure whether its a direct implementation of Observer Pattern, Dojo Toolkit already has in-built event system.

**Dojo Connect:**
dojo.connect could be both used to connect DOM events to their handlers or could be used to wire-up any function to any other function.

```
dojo.connect(obj, event, context, method);
```

**Publish/Subscribe:**
Dojo's Publish/Subscribe could be used to define app-wide topics and then attach/detach handlers to them.

```
dojo.subscribe(topic, method);
dojo.publish(topic, parameters);
```

Links:

- http://docs.dojocampus.org/quickstart/events
- http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/connect
- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-dojoconnect/

Both of these techniques, returns a token which could be used to disconnect the handlers.

Answer (score 2):

I found an observer pattern for javascript in these slides http://www.slideshare.net/rmsguhan/javascript-design-patterns on slide 31.

I've typed it up here

```
// The Observer Object - One who super sees all the print operations
function printManager(){
    var queue = [];

    //The attach method
    this.addJob = function(name, job){
        queue.push({"name":name,"job":job});
    }

    //the detach method
    this.removeJOb = function(job){
        var _queue = [];
        for(var i in queue){
            if(queue[i].job == job)
                continue;
            else
                _queue.push(queue[i]);
        }
        queue = _queue;
    } ...
```

I made a modified version of this (specific to my use) and it worked fine. It was a good starting point for me.